# Is there a way to create templates for worksheets and dashboards in tableau?

Tags: excel, tableau-api

I need to create some visualizations based on departmental metrics to show quarterly progress of projects.  I can upload the excel file and develop what I need. My question is how can I save these worksheets and dashboards, perhaps in some sort of a template, so when more data is entered into the excel file (current quarter progress) I can upload the revised excel file back into Tableau and use the same worksheets and dashboard to display the updated data?

No columns are changed within the excel file, we are just adding additional rows of data or updating dates in existing columns as projects pass milestones.

I am using Tableau Desktop 2019.4.3

I am very new to using Tableau and am looking forward to learning more. I hope my question makes sense and appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you just need to replace the "old" excel file from the datasource pane.

Once you saved your twb/twbx file, when you get the new version of the file, just go to the datasource pane and replace the previous file with the new one.

If the structure (column names and types) is the same, your entire workbook (both worksheets and dashboards) will update.

[I assume you're talking about your worbook using just Tableau Desktop]

Comment: if this helped and solved your needs, please accept the answer in order to close the thread